# Calculate View Projection Matrix

Tags: c++, opengl

The first part of the prgm part states

> In the Camera class, implement the ViewProjection transform, the
>   projection transform is already implemented, and the view transform is
>   implemented in the Static Camera class

My camera Class contains this snippet

```
glm::mat4 Camera::GetViewProjectionMatrix() const
{
    // @TODO 1 - Calculate View Projection Matrix
    glm::mat4 viewProjection(1.0f); // identity, you need to change this

    return viewProjection;
}

glm::mat4 Camera::GetProjectionMatrix() const
{
    return glm::perspective(45.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
}
```

and my StaticCamera Class contains

```
StaticCamera::StaticCamera(glm::vec3 position, glm::vec3 lookAtPoint, glm::vec3 upVector) 
    : Camera(), mPosition(position), mLookAtPoint(lookAtPoint), mUpVector(upVector)
{
}

StaticCamera::~StaticCamera()
{
}

void StaticCamera::Update(float dt)
{
    EventManager::EnableMouseCursor();
}

glm::mat4 StaticCamera::GetViewMatrix() const
{
    return glm::lookAt(     mPosition,      // Camera position
                            mLookAtPoint,   // Look towards this point
                            mUpVector       // Up vector
                        );
}
```

so what I understood was to calculate MVP therefore can i add this to the Camera Class ?

```
glm::mat4 Camera::GetViewProjectionMatrix() const
{
    // @TODO 1 - Calculate View Projection Matrix
    glm::mat4 viewProjection(1.0f); // identity, you need to change this

    //Our ModelViewProjection : multiplication of our 3 matrices
    glm::mat4 MVP = viewProjection * GetViewMatrix() * GetViewProjectionMatrix();

    return MVP;
}
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
glm::mat4 Camera::GetViewProjectionMatrix() const
{
    return GetProjectionMatrix() * GetViewMatrix();
}
```

The transforms are applied intuitively in the following order:

```
Model -> View -> Projection
```

The model matrix brings the object into world space. The view matrix brings the world into view/camera space. The projection matrix then projects the view space into a 2D projected space.

Because matrix multiplication is applied 'backwards', you get:

```
Projection * View * Model
```

In this case your function is returning just the ViewProjection matrix and not the ModelViewProjection, so you apply only those transforms.

Answer (score 1):

You are usually using 3 Matrices:

Model-Matrix - Descripes the Object

View-Matrix - Descripes position and direction of the camera

Proj-Matrix - Descripes camera parameters like field of view etc.

A combination of these matrices for example the ViewProjectionMatrix is just a multiplication of the base matrices.

```
mat4 ViewProj= Proj*View; //note: order is reversed
```

Comment: So would the GetViewProjectionMatrix return the following?
glm::mat4 VP =  GetViewProjectionMatrix() * viewProjection;

Comment: also what does this stand for?? glm::mat4 viewProjection(1.0f); // identity, you need to change this

Comment: You need to provide the view projection matrix. So projection * view;

Comment: The model matrix brings the object into world space. The view matrix brings the worldspace into view/camera space. The projection matrix then projects the view space into a 2D projected space;